# Replacing spaces with underscores within each capture group in Vim using regex

Tags: regex, string, vim, replace, powerbi

I often edit Power Query "M" code using Vim while working with Power BI. Typically I prefer to change the auto-generated identifier names for each
query step by replacing spaces with underscores and shifting it to lowercase. Identifiers with spaces are represented as #-prefixed quoted strings
such as `#"Change Column Types"`. For that example, I would like every instance to be transformed to `change_column_types` instead.
I would like to create a keymapping that can do this within any buffer for all instances.

An example file is shown below, followed by the desired 'cleaned' file:

Input:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"foo", type text}, {"bar", type text}, {"baz", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([foo] = "sdf")),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"bar"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Desired output:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    changed_type = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"foo", type text}, {"bar", type text}, {"baz", Int64.Type}}),
    filtered_rows = Table.SelectRows(changed_type, each ([foo] = "sdf")),
    grouped_rows = Table.Group(filtered_rows, {"bar"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    grouped_rows
```

The trick is that this involves trying to replace multiple (an unknown number of) characters within each capture group.
Since there are only usually 2 or 3 words in each, I can handle these in a hacky way using two ex commands:

```
:%s/\v\#"(\w+)\s(\w+)"/\L\1_\L\2/gc
:%s/\v\#"(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)"/\L\1_\L\2_\L\3/gc
```

However, this obviously does not seem ideal given that it is hardcoded to support only certain numbers of words.
I have tried doing some nested grouping but the problem still seems to be the same.
Is there a way to define a replacement pattern within some other replacement operation?
Any help on how to properly handle this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following creates a mapping for `<space>`-`<c>` to convert the strings to identifiers:

```
noremap <space>c :%s/#"\([^"]\+\)"/\=substitute(tolower(submatch(1)), " ", "_", "g")/g<CR>
```

A little explanation on what's happening here-  the `\=` part of the replacement portion of the substitution signifies that we're going to evaluate this expression as vim script rather than treat it as literal text. We use `submatch(1)` to get the text of the first capture group, convert it to lowercase, and then perform a second substitution (spaces to underscores).

---

Note, there are a few edge cases this can snag on- if need be, I can edit the regex to be more complex (and potentially brittle) to handle these cases.

- If strings can start with a single quote instead of double quote, this won't match them. I have no idea if that's an issue Power Query "M" would have.
- If the strings contain escaped characters (backslashes), this won't handle that.
- If the string starts with a number, this may not make a valid identifier in the target language / format (if its like most languages).